# Rewriting `c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r` into "normal" presentation

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
```

I've rewritten it like that:

```
if (c > 3 && r) {
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, r);
}

return r;
```

Have I got it right?

Comment: Yep, those are equivalent.

Comment: @ssube how.......

Comment: @ssube, thanks, just wanted to get second opinion :)

Comment: @Mahi the `&&` and `,` operators in JS are a little wonky. Hang on, I'll put together a CW answer.

Comment: @Mahi check below for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @ssube i am waiting to upvote :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, those are equivalent. You caught both potential problems: the `&&` returning an operand and the `,` skipping that return value.

As you can see (for the `x, y`) part, the value of the first operand is disregarded. The comma operator simply evaluates the first expression, it doesn't care what happens (unless an exception is thrown). For example:

```js
console.log((true && false, 3));
```

The `&&` operator will evaluated the first operand and short-circuit if it was false, otherwise evaluating the second operand *and returning* its result. That means the `Object.defineProperty` only runs if `c > 3 && r`, which you captured. While the `,` operator then discards the result, `defineProperty` has already mutated the object.